# Converting struct with embedded interface into JSON

Tags: go

I have a struct that I want to marshal to JSON. It has a defined field called `Foo` (exported as `foo`) and a `data` interface field to which I want to pass a dynamic struct with additional JSON fields.

However when the data field is an interface instead of the specific struct it never gets exported as JSON. How can I make this work?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type data interface{}

type foo struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo,omitempty"`
    data
}

type bar struct {
    Bar string `json:"bar,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    b := bar{"bar"}
    f := foo{"foo", b}

    byt, err := json.Marshal(f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(byt))
}
```

I need to output to look like this (it needs to be flat, not nested):

```
{"foo": "foo", "bar": "bar"}
```

Comment: I doubt you can. Most probably you have to encode data for itself and plug it into the rest.

Comment: @Volker could you illustrate your idea with a sample code snippet?

Comment: There’re 2 options:

Comment: One major issue is that `data` is an unexported type, which means that the `data` embedded field is unexported.  The JSON package does not handle unexported members.  It must be exported in order to be marshalled, though that still doesn't solve your flat-json requirement (it marshals as `{"foo":"foo","Data":{"bar":"bar"}}`)

Comment: @Kaedys but it would work as:
type foo struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo,omitempty"`
    bar
} ; that way I don't need to export bar but I can just embed it

Comment: Right, you can embed a _struct_, because the fields of that struct get promoted and handled by the JSON.  `foo.Bar` would be a valid reference in that case.  But if you wrap the struct in an interface, the field name of the interface has to be exported, which means it either has to be named or, if embedded, the interface type itself has to be exported.

Comment: It's a mild oddity of the reflection package (which is what JSON uses to marshal) that exported fields of an embedded unexported struct are accessible, but embedded unexported interfaces are not.  Odd, but that's the way it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this with a custom [json.Marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) implementation and a little bit of byte slicing.

```
func (f foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type goo foo
    g := goo(f)

    b1, err := json.Marshal(g)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    b2, err := json.Marshal(g.data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    s1 := string(b1[:len(b1)-1])
    s2 := string(b2[1:])

    return []byte(s1 + ", " + s2), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/NYTNWIL-xu

Please note that this is not checking whether the bytes can actually be sliced and it does also not consider the possible case of the `data` field being a slice or an array, which i'm unsure how you would want that flattened anyway.

Comment: Could you explain why `type goo foo` is needed, why does running the same code on `f` itself cause stack overflow?

Comment: `type goo foo` defines a new type `goo` with the same structure as `foo`, but only the structure. That means that `foo`'s methods are not available on `goo`, including the caller `MarshalJSON`, while the fields `Foo` and `data` are. So then `json.Marshal(g)` will not end up calling `goo.MarshalJSON`, since it doesn't exist, which avoids the stack overflow. And so if you don't declare the new type, and you call `json.Marshal(f)` while `foo.MarshalJSON` itself also calls `json.Marshal(f)` you'll cause infinite recursion.

Comment: So, basically, the only purpose of `type goo foo` is to avoid the stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks, all makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

I would write a custom marshaller, like so:

```
func (f foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type tmp foo
    g := tmp(f)
    first, err := json.Marshal(g)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    second, err := json.Marshal(f.data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal(first, &data)
    json.Unmarshal(second, &data)
    return json.Marshal(data)
    //{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TENiCe9nR0

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. Set to it type `json.RawMessage` so it won’t be decoded automatically and left as an interface.  https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage
2. Write custom unmarshaler on the structure.